# Postgres: How to JOIN

Tags: postgresql

I am working on Postgres 9.3. I have two tables, the first for payment items:

```
                   Table "public.prescription"
      Column       |          Type           |                             Modifiers
-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_prescription_id_seq'::regclass)
 presentation_code | character varying(15)   | not null
 presentation_name | character varying(1000) | not null
 actual_cost       | double precision        | not null
 pct_id            | character varying(3)    | not null
```

And the second for organisations:

```
           Table "public.pct"
      Column       |          Type           | Modifiers
-------------------+-------------------------+-----------
 code              | character varying(3)    | not null
 name              | character varying(200)  |
```

I have a query to get all the payments for a particular code:

```
SELECT sum(actual_cost) as total_cost, pct_id as row_id 
FROM prescription 
WHERE presentation_code='1234' GROUP BY pct_id
```

Here is the [query plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/FJS) for that query.

Now, I'd like to annotate each row with the `name` property of the associated organisation. This is what I'm trying:

```
SELECT sum(prescription.actual_cost) as total_cost, prescription.pct_id, pct.name as row_id
FROM prescription, pct
WHERE prescription.presentation_code='0212000AAAAAAAA'
GROUP BY prescription.pct_id, pct.name;
```

Here's the [ANALYSE for that query](http://explain.depesz.com/s/cjjE). It's incredibly slow: what am I doing wrong?

I think there must be a way to annotate each row with the `pct.name` AFTER the first query has run, which would be faster.

Comment: You are not joining at all. Please see the manual on how to do this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html and  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JOIN (LEFT JOIN in this case, because we want the line even if there is no pct):

```
SELECT 
    sum(prescription.actual_cost) as total_cost,
    prescription.pct_id,
    pct.name as row_id
FROM prescription
    LEFT JOIN pct ON pct.code = prescription.pct_id
WHERE 
    prescription.presentation_code='0212000AAAAAAAA'
GROUP BY 
    prescription.pct_id,
    pct.name;
```

I don't know if it's work well, I didn't try this query.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking data from 2 tables, but you do not join the tables in any way. Effectively, you make a full join, resulting in the Cartesian product of both tables. If you look at your `ANALYZE` statistics, you see that your nested loop processes 62 million rows. that takes time.

Add in a join condition to make this all fast:

```
SELECT sum(prescription.actual_cost) as total_cost, prescription.pct_id, pct.name as row_id
FROM prescription
JOIN pct On pct.code = prescription.pct_id
WHERE prescription.presentation_code = '0212000AAAAAAAA'
GROUP BY prescription.pct_id, pct.name;
```